# How many controllers does OS X support?

Tags: steam, controllers, macos

Dear fellow Steam on OS X players,

I wonder how many controllers can be connected either per USB or paired via Bluetooth to OS X? I have just one PS4 dualshock which works perfectly with my Macbook Pro, but I want to know if it supports another one, and if possible, up to four controllers?

Comment: did you succeed ? i'm trying to figure out why it doesn't work properly on my osx...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible to connect up to four controllers having a maximum of 7 connections through *USB* and unlimited number of connections through *pairing*, as long as your game supports multiplayer. You should check this [out](https://superuser.com/questions/931188/how-many-ps3-ps4-controllers-can-be-hooked-up-to-one-pc-bluetooth-adapter-at-a-t).

Comment: ahh superusers. of course :)

Answer (score 2):

**Answering for the USB side of things.**

OS X itself should be able to detect up to 127 total USB connected devices through a single port.

I highly recommend reading this: https://superuser.com/a/330570/259665

I would also recommend getting a 4-port, powered USB hub to make sure that USB lag is not a factor when 4 people are actively using a controller.

---

If you actually want to connect 127 devices then it would require very careful planning to make sure that all of the USB hubs are powered properly.

Furthermore, if you actually connect 127 devices through one USB port then expect some very extreme lag when using your controller.